# how to stop pagination on last image

Tags: jquery

There is image pagination example. Everything is fine, but when I reach pagination end it starts again (starts from first image again). How can I stop pagination on last image.

HTML:

```
<div class="img-list">
<img src="" alt="1" />
<img src="" alt="2" />
<img src="" alt="3" />
<img src="" alt="4" />
<img src="" alt="5" />
<img src="" alt="6" />
<img src="" alt="7" />
<img src="" alt="8" />
<img src="" alt="9" />
<img src="" alt="10" />
<img src="" alt="11" />
<img src="" alt="12" />
<img src="" alt="13" />
<img src="" alt="14" />
<img src="" alt="15" />
</div>
<a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
<a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
```

jQuery:

```
var start = 0;
var nb = 5;
var end = start + nb;
var length = $('.img-list img').length;
var list = $('.img-list img');

list.hide().filter(':lt('+(end)+')').show();


$('.prev, .next').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

if( $(this).hasClass('prev') ){
  start -= nb;
} else {
   start += nb;
}

if( start < 0 || start >= length ) start = 0;
end = start + nb;       

if( start == 0 ) list.hide().filter(':lt('+(end)+')').show();
else list.hide().filter(':lt('+(end)+'):gt('+(start-1)+')').show();
});
```

Comment: Try below my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var start = 0;
var nb = 5;
var end = start + nb;
var length = $('.img-list img').length;
var list = $('.img-list img');

list.hide().filter(':lt('+(end)+')').show();


$('.prev, .next').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

if( $(this).hasClass('prev') ){
  start -= nb;
} else {
  if(start!=10) //add this line
   start += nb;
}

if( start < 0 || start >= length ) start = 0;
end = start + nb;       

if( start == 0 ) list.hide().filter(':lt('+(end)+')').show();
else list.hide().filter(':lt('+(end)+'):gt('+(start-1)+')').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-list">
<img src="" alt="1" />
<img src="" alt="2" />
<img src="" alt="3" />
<img src="" alt="4" />
<img src="" alt="5" />
<img src="" alt="6" />
<img src="" alt="7" />
<img src="" alt="8" />
<img src="" alt="9" />
<img src="" alt="10" />
<img src="" alt="11" />
<img src="" alt="12" />
<img src="" alt="13" />
<img src="" alt="14" />
<img src="" alt="15" />
</div>
<a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
<a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
```

Try this...
add  this line `if(start!=10)`

```
var start = 0;
var nb = 5;
var end = start + nb;
var length = $('.img-list img').length;
var list = $('.img-list img');

list.hide().filter(':lt('+(end)+')').show();


$('.prev, .next').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

if( $(this).hasClass('prev') ){
  start -= nb;
} else {
  if(start!=10) //add this line
   start += nb;
}

if( start < 0 || start >= length ) start = 0;
end = start + nb;       

if( start == 0 ) list.hide().filter(':lt('+(end)+')').show();
else list.hide().filter(':lt('+(end)+'):gt('+(start-1)+')').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag to observe last end.It's work for me.Try it.

```js
var start = 0;
var last_end = 0;
var nb = 5;
var end = start + nb;
var length = $('.img-list img').length;
var list = $('.img-list img');

list.hide().filter(':lt(' + (end) + ')').show();

$('.prev, .next').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
        start -= nb;
        last_end -= nb;
    } else {
        start += nb;
    }

    if (start < 0 || start >= length) start = 0;
    end = start + nb;

    if (last_end == length) {
        start = length - nb
        end = length
    }

    if (start == 0) list.hide().filter(':lt(' + (end) + ')').show();
    else list.hide().filter(':lt(' + (end) + '):gt(' + (start - 1) + ')').show();

    if (end == length) {
        last_end = end
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tag-wrapper">
    <div class="img-list">
        <img src="" alt="1" />
        <img src="" alt="2" />
        <img src="" alt="3" />
        <img src="" alt="4" />
        <img src="" alt="5" />
        <img src="" alt="6" />
        <img src="" alt="7" />
        <img src="" alt="8" />
        <img src="" alt="9" />
        <img src="" alt="10" />
        <img src="" alt="11" />
        <img src="" alt="12" />
        <img src="" alt="13" />
        <img src="" alt="14" />
        <img src="" alt="15" />
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="prev">Prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks MD.Moniruzzaman. But this code does not work properly. Its shows all images and pagination does not work.

Comment: Your question have to stop last image pagination so above code fulfill  your requirement.

Comment: Thanks MD.Moniruzzaman. Your code works. I a little bit changed this code and it works. I appreciate your help.